# Migrant from VS 2003 .Net1.1 to VS 2008 .Net 2.0

Tags: visual-studio-2008

I converted my app that was implemented in VS 2003 to .net 2.0 VS 2008
afterward my app became slow about 4 times than previous version!

is it normal or not ?
Best regards

Answer (score 0):

No. I have never heard of such a performance degradation before from upgrading the target framework.

.NET 2.0 uses another version of the CLR than 1.1, so there might be small differences. Perhaps you are running into some edge case, but we really can't tell without any more information.

Comment: all codes implemented behind the form and Dataset and sqladapter was used for it 

regards